# Show keyboard with textField when pressing uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, keyboard

I have a button:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addTaskBtn;
```

...

```
// Add new task button action.
- (IBAction)addTaskBtnAction:(id)sender {

}
```

I want a keyboard with a textfield accessory toolbar to pop up when I press my button. That textfield should also become the firstresponder which causes kind of a paradox...

I find it impossible to show a keyboard without making it a first responder of an existing textfiled, but I am trying to create a textfield as a toolbar of a keyboard.

The best example for this is in this app: https://todoist.com/ - they managed to do exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can make a hidden textfield which will become first responder when you want to show the keyboard

Comment: I tried that. The problem is if that hidden textfield pulls up the keyboard, how would I make my toolbar accessory that's attached to said keyboard the first responder? I

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the hidden textfield:
make txtHidden as hidden and make it first responder on button click

```
- (IBAction)btnOpenTextfield:(id)sender {
    [self.txtHidden becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) setupToolbar {
    UIToolbar *keyboardToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 42)];
    self.txtToolbar = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 6, 250, 30)];
    UIBarButtonItem *textBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.txtToolbar ];
    UIBarButtonItem *postBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Post" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(postComment)];
    [keyboardToolBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textBtn,postBtn,nil]];
    self.txtHidden.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.txtHidden) {
        [self setupToolbar];
    }
    return true;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self changeResponder];
}

- (void) changeResponder {
    [self.txtToolbar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This is not the best way but you can try this till you get any other better solution

Comment: @mic773 , does this help you, please tick answer as yes so other's can also get benefit from it